# Pasar fecha de un datapicker a una ruta json

Tags: php, json, laravel-7

Amigos, tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un datepicker donde selecciono una fecha, y esa fecha la paso a través de una url json, pero mi problema se genera que la ruta me lee cualquier cosa del campo fecha y no se como traspasarla para recibirla en mi controlador

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label> Fecha</label>
    <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-calendar22"></i></span></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control daterange-single Fecha" value="{{old('fecha')}}" maxlength="10" name="fecha" id="fecha" required>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
      function getRespuesta(fecha){
         var fecha1 = $("#fecha").val();
         console.log(fecha1);  //lo que me trae 20/04/2021

         url="{{route('fechas.getRespuesta', ["fecha"=>"#FECHA#"])}}";
         url=url.replace("#FECHA#", $("#fecha_ini").val());
         console.log(url);
         $.getJSON(url, {}, function (data) {
           console.log(data);
              swal.close();
              $("#bloques option").remove();
              //console.log(data);
               $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (i, item) {
                   //aca debo mostrar unas opciones con checkbox, que tampoco se como obtener
               });
            })
      }
   });
</script>
```

Si imprimo `console.log(url);`, esto me trae de respuesta el siguiente link http://127.0.0.1:8000/respuestas/getRespuestas?fecha=%23REF%23 y obviamente necesito pasar mi fecha `?fecha=24-04-2021` y no se como hacerlo, y tampoco se como armar unos checkbox que traigo de respuesta al seleccionar la fecha.

Ayuda por favor

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu duda. Debe usar AJAX para pasar en tu ruta el valor de la fecha que necesitas y en tu controlador validar que sea un valor de tipo date.

Comment: Soy nulo con ajax, alguna orientación para poder hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

No es tan complicado cuando le tienes la práctica suficiente. Mi manera preferida de hacerlo es con [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Haciendo uso de fetch sería de la siguiente manera:

```js
const fecha = document.getElementById('date');
const consultar = document.getElementById('send');
const url = "{{ url(route/path) }}"
consultar.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(fecha.value)
  fetch(`${url}?fecha=${fecha.value}`)
    .then(res => res.json()) //recibirás tu respuesta en formato json
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

```html
<input id="date" type="date">
<button id="send">Consultar</button>
```

Y en tu controlador solo debes tener algo como esto:

```
public function methodData(Request $request)
{
   $data = Validator::make($request->all() ,[
      'fecha' => ['required', 'date']
   ]);
}
```